# siunitx update of 2022-08-08

Tags: siunitx

I upgraded siunitx to the version of 2022-08-08 and obtain the following error message: "ERROR: LaTeX Error: Key 'siunitx/number-mode' accepts only a fixed set of choices."
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The error is trying to be helpful: you have `number-mode` somewhere with an incorrect value (or at least one that appears to be incorrect to the current code). Please post a minimal working example showing the issue.

Comment: I also have this problem. It happens when using the powerdot presentations package.

Comment: A minimal example is as follows:

\documentclass[style=simple,mode=print]{powerdot}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\end{document}

This generates the Error "! LaTeX Error: Key 'siunitx/number-mode' accepts only a fixed set of choices."

From the log file, it appears that importing amsgen.sty triggers the error, but that's not under my control.

Can I do anything, or is this a problem for the author of powerdot?